# Can I change the overlap order with negative margins in CSS?

Tags: html, css, layer

I have a list, for which on `li:hover` the `li` gains a bottom border (it already had a top one). Unfortunately this results in two adjacent borders, so now 2px wide which is not good. So I figured I could just chuck on a `margin-bottom:-1px;` on hover and it'd be ok, but unfortunately the bottom element is overlapping the current one, so I'm getting an incorrect border colour.

I wishfully tried doing `z-index:1;`, but that's not doing anything. To me, that should be the way to do it. Come on W3C!

I can't use `position`:

- `absolute` is a no go as I need it to be in-flow.
- `relative` is a no go as the `li`s have child `ul`s that need to be positioned relative to the parent `ul`.

Is there any way to have the prior element overlap the next element upon adding negative margin?

For now I'll probably have to do some jQuery hacking, was so close to getting it all done via CSS!

Comment: can you fiddle it? it would be easier to understand

Comment: @Hiral This - http://jsfiddle.net/2nNzS/ - is the basic idea. When you hover on an element, both the top and bottom borders should go a full black. But unfortunately, instead you see the overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but just in case, try the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) . If I understand your question correctly, then the following should work:

```
li:hover + li{border-top:none !important;}
```

maybe you don't need the !important declaration, but just in case. Also, with this technique you could use it for the negative margin as you mention (or whatever you need)

Comment: Yep you must have understood it because that worked! Thank you for opening my mind to adjacent selectors, wow the potential! I didn't need to use `!important`, I make a big effort to avoid that in my CSS.

Comment: glad to be of help :)